# Install Windows on a usb flash drive from Ubuntu

Tags: usb, system-installation, windows

I want to install a Windows version on a USB flash drive from Ubuntu. How can I do it and which version of Windows should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you would run Windows from inside Ubuntu? Then you would need to use virtualbox. Download it and run it, and create a vdi file. Then put the file into your usb, point the virtualbox at it, (or make another machine with the existing vdi file), and you would be good to go.

Comment: I don't want to use virtualbox or anything like that. I want to INSTALL a Windows version on a usb flash drive so I can run it whenever I want to and make changes on it. Not just create a bootable drive.

Comment: Ok I see. That's going to be tough. You may consider virtualbox, its a real install and you can make changes to it, install stuff on it, basically anything you can do with a normal install. Good luck!

Comment: Running Windows in a virtual box on Ubuntu from a flash drive is painfully slow with USB2 with USB3 and over 8GB RAM it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only method of installing Windows to flash drive I have ever managed to get to work, it works with XP but is slow.

http://tdoui.webs.com/Install%20And%20Run%20Windwos%20XP%20From%20USB.pdf

The modified files are available on the internet.

I'm not sure why this question is asked in a Ubuntu web site though.